# When is it a good idea to submit a form via AJAX vs Server Side submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working with jQuery / AJAX and ASP.NET. I'm creating two forms, create and update.

For this project I've gotten in the habit of doing everything via AJAX including submitting the the create form and populating the update form.

Are there any guidelines on when you should use AJAX and when you should do the work server side. Both will get the job done and I'm just wondering if I'm overdoing it on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: Doing *what* work server-side?  Submitting a form with ajax already involves the server doing at least *something*.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, if you're going to use AJAX you should use [progressive enhancement](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ajax-progressive-enhancement/), so that it will work if the user doesn't have JavaScript turned on. That would mean that you always build out the server side structure, and then build the AJAX on top of it.

But, if you opt to require that your users have Javascript, then it becomes a question of whether or not it's worth the time/money investment. Ask yourself if you're just adding AJAX because it's cool, or because it significantly improves the workflow for the user.

In the case of an add/edit form, I probably wouldn't bother with AJAX for the whole form, since it's a pretty simple process for the user. The exception would be if I needed to validate some of fields against a database or something. e.g., check if the username they're requesting is already taken.

That's assuming you have a simple form, though. If you want to describe the purpose and kinds of fields you have, I can give more specific feedback on your situation.

Comment: Or you could just follow the Microsoft SP2010 footsteps -- no JavaScript = not a snowballs chance in a vat of boiling oil of working ;-)

Comment: a user with javascript turned off is a user you don't want/need, progressive enhancement is cool when it comes to css or specific js APIs (ex. localStorage) but plz don't spend a single dev minute on a user that has js turned off, just my pov

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate the idea of "Progressive Enhancements". This started because I created a form with four cascading drop down lists State > Area > County > Facility. When I attempted to submit the form server side the DDLs kept on returning blank results. When I was writing the update code, I was having issues with filling in the DDLs serverside. If had been able to resolve these issues I would have stayed with the server side code.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I think that a chain of dropdown lists which are dependent on each other is a great example of where AJAX is appropriate. A traditional approach would require the user to submit the form 4 times to complete it, instead of just once with AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience when it gets serious (ex. payment process) users prefer page refreshes as an indicator for "something is happening, something has worked".

So my best practice is: i try to implement everything with ajax calls (always showing process spinners) but sign ups, logins, payments always work in the old-school way.

2nd thing you might consider is sessions. If you have a form that results in session updates it might be a good idea to refresh the page afterwards, so old-school is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically any time you don't want the browser to load a whole new page after submitting the form.

If the form includes file upload inputs, however, i think there are some hacks you have to do involving an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is said by ezmilhouse,I think ,if you don't understand the AJAX concept,and don't have enough information about it, Don't use it in redundant manner, because using Ajax is so easy in the simlest way in asp.net,some drag and drop an update panel on the whole page or in the master page and use it in every thing and this is so wrong.